# Get Taxonmy Term ID For Current Post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

If I wanted to get the category ID for the current post, I would use something like this:

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_ID . ' '; } ?>
```

How can I do the same for a a term ID from a specific Taxonomy?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks helgatheviking, it didn't work as is but you definitely set me on the right path. I got it working by doing the following:

```
<?php foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'your-taxonomy-here')) as $term) { echo $term->term_id. ''; } ?>
```

Replace "your-taxonomy-here" with your own and your ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

See [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms), you'd do something like so:

```
foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID) as $term) { echo $term->term_id. '<br/>'; }
```